# AngularJS Isolated Scope Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with setting the isolated scope of a directive on a Angular App:

Here is my `app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    if ($scope.name == 'bob') {
        console.log("It's bob")
    }else if ($scope.name == 'joe') {
        console.log("It's joe")
    }else if ($scope.name == 'mary') {
        console.log("It's mary")
    }
}]);

app.directive('test', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        replace : true,
        templateUrl :  'test.html',
        scope: {
            name : '@'
        }
        controller : 'mainController'
    };
});
```

(`Main.html`) looks something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
      <div>
          /* This is where I set the name in the directive */
          <test name="bob"></test>
      </div>      
</div>
```

`Test.html`:

```
<div>{{name}}</div>
```

Now for some reason when I run the above `HTML` code none of the print statements happen in my mainController.

If I set a custom scope object in the `directive` does that mean the directive `test` doesn't have access to the `mainController` which is the controller I passed in to the directive under the `controller` key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **@ binding** is for passing strings. These strings support {{}}
> expressions for interpolated values. For example: . The interpolated
> expression is evaluated against directive's parent scope.
>
> **= binding** is for two-way model binding. The model in parent scope is linked to the model in the directive's isolated scope. Changes to one
> model affects the other, and vice versa.

Please find a working code example below - with a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rzfc22r/) link.

**VIEW**

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])


app.directive('test', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      name: '@'
    },
    controller: 'nameController',
    template: '<div>{{name}}</div>'

  }
})


app.controller('nameController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  if ($scope.name == 'bob') {
    console.log("It's bob")
  } else if ($scope.name == 'joe') {
    console.log("It's joe")
  } else if ($scope.name == 'mary') {
    console.log("It's mary")
  }else {
    console.log("It's someone else")
  }
}]);
```

Have a look at the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rzfc22r/)

Comment: Hello @daan, I just realized I am not using the ng-repeat anymore but just want to pass the name to the directive in the HTML and then based on the value of the name I pass to the directive, it should console.log the correct name. Sorry for the confusion. I tried the updated code above in my post but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: In that case have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/3rzfc22r/. Does that solve your questions?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, Thank you very much the code is working now!

Answer (score 1):

first you are using `name : '@'` that is used for one way binding i.e change will be within that directive scope only if you want to use two way binding you need to use `name : '='`

Answer (score 1):

If you bind your attribute to scope using '@' it will basically look for a string.

So you have to either use a combination of:

```
name : '@'
<test name={{obj.name}}></test>
```

or

```
name : '='
<test name=obj.name></test>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have some recursion use there. when you use `test` you use again `mainController`, also in your template.

make a main html file, use `mainController` there, and remove `ng-controller="mainController"` from test.html and remove `controller : 'mainController'` from the directive and try again.

also please make us a plunker

Comment: Hello if I remove `controller : 'mainController'` from the directive how will it know that the console.log statements are in the `mainController` controller?

Comment: daan gave you the full answer, exactly what i meant

Comment: Yeah he gave a very comprehensive answer. But yeah I realized what you were saying and my mistake. Thanks.